# How to add remove dynamic elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This code works when adding a dynamic table with data coming from an ajax request but can not remove the dynamic table. I code below shows whenever I click on a tree node, it should load its mysql table data into a HTML table.

```
     $("#treeNodes").on("select_node.jstree", function(event, data)
     {
           var node = data.rslt.obj;
           var nodeID = node.attr("id");
           event.stopImmediatePropagation;
           if(/leaf/.test(nodeID))
           {
                $(".tableData > *").remove(); // remove all table data (tr rows) before adding the new data and not working or firing off.
                addTableData(); // This function get the data from a mysql table and loads it into an HTML table.
           }

     });

     <table>
            <tbody class='tableData'></tbody>
    </table>
```

Would someone kindly show me how this code can recognize the newly added dynamic table data so it can be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('.tableData').empty();
```

The `empty()` method removes all descendants and text from the element(s) it was called on.

Comment: not working using $('.tableData').empty(), so how its not seeing the newly added table data but when I load the page table data, the $('.tableData').remove(), it works.

Comment: I had to go up one parent level and it worked using the table id instead of the tbody id

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(".tableData").html("");
```

but what anOG wrote is faster.  so use `empty()` instead.